# Cannot call a class as a function in moment using in react native

Tags: react-native, momentjs, date-conversion

I am trying to convert string to date using moment. but it gives me error as Cannot call a class as a function.

```
import moment from 'react-moment';


 let dayOfToday = getDayFromDate(bookingDate) + " " + `${timeSlot.end}`; //2019-20-10 10:00 AM
   // let dateBooking = new Date(dayOfToday); // this function works in simulator but in device i am getting invalid date
   let dateBooking = moment(dayOfToday).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm A');
```

How to use moment in react native

Comment: can you mention one sample input date that you are getting from api and result that you want?

Comment: Have you added `moment` dependency?

Comment: This is the 2019-20-10 10:00 AM i want to covert

Comment: @ravibagul91 what kind of dependency

Comment: To use `react-moment` you should also add `moment` as dependency.

Comment: @ravibagul91 installed moment but its a same problem

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should run npm install moment to add moment;
 Secondly, in the component, import it.

```
import moment from "moment
```

Finally, in the place where you want to convert string to data

```
moment("converTime").format("YYYY-DD-MM")
```

In my project, I use below steps to convert string to date